# HighStock baseSeries value is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am not able to update the value of baseSeries field under Navigator in HighStock chart.

here is fiddle example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/HwuRr/6/

$(function () {

```
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

navigator: {
        baseSeries: 2
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{

        data: [4,6,2,1,2,3,4]
    },{

        data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    },{

        data: [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
    }]
}, function (chart) {

    $('#btn').click(function(){

        chart.options.navigator.baseSeries = 1;

    });

});
```

});

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
         chart.series[3].setData([5,2,1,2,4,6,10]);
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HwuRr/11/

Comment: thanks for you help. but is there any way that i can just set the baseSeries value not the data. For example, I am getting the baseSeries value like(0,1,2 etc.) and i need to show that series in navigator.

Comment: You cannot change baseseries value directly. If you need to use series[3] data in the navigator, then you need to place the contents inside setData. This is the only way.

Comment: changing the navigator data this way just changes which data is used to plot the line shown in the navigator. It doesn't affect which series gets panned (if you have separate xAxes)